# Как сжимать данные из выхода mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, база-данных, ubuntu, amazon

Пример команды которая работает, она отправляет данные, на сервер s3

```
mysqldump -u root -pByrjuybnj123 development | python mysql.py
```

Хотелось бы получать данные с mysql, сжать, и отправлять их уже в s3

Comment: ну так и вставьте между ними архивацию `mysqldump | gzip - | python` если конечно ваш питоновский скрипт готов принимать архивированные данные

Comment: архивировать там нечего — нет набора файлов/каталогов. судя по ответу и комментариям, подразумевалось **сжатие**, а не **архивация**.

Comment: интересует архивация, вопрос решен)

Answer (score 3):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
mysqldump -u root -pByrjuybnj123 development | gzip -c | python mysql.py
```

Comment: Я добавил максимальную степень сжатия, т.к. архив в памяти хранится, а потом стримится в s3, mysqldump -u root -pByrjuybnj123 development | gzip -9 -c | python mysql.py